# Getting obscure error when using Google sign-in in Android

Tags: android, google-signin

I'm getting `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:` when trying to use [Google sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#start_the_sign-in_flow).

Here is the code itself:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        //handleSignInResult(task);
        GoogleSignInAccount account = getAccount(task);
        System.out.println("asti00");
    }
}

public GoogleSignInAccount getAccount(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
    GoogleSignInAccount account = null;
    try {
        account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
    } catch (ApiException ex) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("asti01");
        System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("asti02");
    }

    return account;
}
```

As you can see I'm using the exact code as in the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) but I'm getting the error `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:`.

I can't figure out where the error is coming from. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: lvanov Check github link https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your app level build.gradle

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'

Answer (score 0):

Your app is not linked to your Google Account. Click on Tools -> Firebase -> Authentication and execute the tutorial (all steps). After that, try again.