# Firebase Google+ Api error : ApiException: 10:

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-plus, google-signin

UPDATE: SO I tested my code on another computer with the android studio and it is working. However, that just brings a new question: Why does the code work well on one computer but not on the other. Both android studio's are the same version, I was tested with the same device.

Before I ask the question let me mention that my code works as a separate app, but once I implement the code into a pre-existing app that I have made I get the exception:

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:

I will include my working code, as well as the once that will not work. But basically, my Logcat detects the problem to be at this line:

```
Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
```

Now I appreciate all possible help, but let me tell you a few that I think are not correct. My app is not released. I did not need a SHA key or any kind of authentication when I used a mock app to test the API.But basically, I found that once I put the same code in a preexisting application, I am getting these problems. Also, I have made sure all of my imports are valid.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Here is where I set up my google API.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    SignInButton googleSignIn= findViewById(R.id.google_sign_in_button);
    googleSignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ButtonPressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            signIn();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // Here is where my Logcat tells me the problem is at.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
            // ...
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                        Log.d(TAG, name+email+phone);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

// Apk of working separate app. 
[My APK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jsWtfrrXTznJU72qw0MZot_ebq9mSF6z/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the full error on logcat
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277411/getting-obscure-error-when-using-google-sign-in-in-android/49265660?noredirect=1#comment85535490_49265660

Comment: are you using the same Firebase project?

Comment: No. I have 2 fire-base projects.

Comment: are you using an emulator?

Comment: yes I am in fact using an emulator.

Comment: But I have also tested on my cell phone now.

Comment: I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] No Fallback module; NOT setting up for lazy initialization
I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.api.GoogleApiActivity (has extras)} from uid 10014 on display 0
D/Google: Google sign in failed